# Regex to find/remove duplicate line

Tags: regex, replace

I have this line, that is sometimes repeated in the html file, and I want to:

1- get a regex to just find files that has that line duplicate

2- get a regex to search and remove the second instance it come on the file, and leave the first.  So it keeps only the first, not the second

Given that the lines are not after each other, they are separated with lots of code and text.

The line is:

```
<script src="/resources/common.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

or it could have words before or after the line that is needed to be removed, like:

```
<script src="/resources/common.js" type="text/javascript"></script><div id=something"...
```

I use Notepad++ to search and replace.

Comment: Which tool/language are you planning to use for this? Also, is it possible that there may be more than two copies of that line in the file (and if so, do you want to remove all but the first)?

Comment: What tool are you using for regular expressions ? sed ? grep ? java ? an editor ?

Comment: Notepad++, and yes, it would be great if there are more to remove them all but the first instance in that file..  Thanks

Comment: I was working in a solution using `grep` and `sed`, but I see you are using Windows. :(

Answer (score 2):

If you were using [EditPad Pro](http://www.editpadpro.com) (or [EditPad Lite](http://www.editpadlite.com), which is free), it would be easy:

Search for

```
(?s)(?<=<script src="/resources/common\.js" type="text/javascript"></script>.*)<script src="/resources/common\.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and replace all with nothing.

A screenshot to clarify:

[image: EPP screenshot]

With other editors, you will have to apply the following regex repeatedly (once for each duplication):

```
(?s)(?<=<script src="/resources/common\.js" type="text/javascript"></script>)(.*?)<script src="/resources/common\.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

but this time replace the match with `\1`.

Comment: That's a better answer than mine. :)

Comment: Thanks both of you for your time..  I'll try EditPad and see, as I need to do that for thousands of files, and NP++ have an option to search and replace something in a whole directory..  I'll see if EP is fast too..

Comment: @Mike RegexBuddy has built in module for applying these patterns using grep, give it a try too. http://www.regexbuddy.com/

Comment: @deadlock: Right, but there is no free version of RegexBuddy (but it's worth every penny).

Comment: I tried the regex suggested in the answer using EditPad but it found nothing.. although the file I was testing with had a duplicate..  perhaps because there were some words after the line?  I updated the question with another example..

Comment: @Mike: It works here - you did activate the "Regex" button in the Search field, didn't you?

Comment: I did.. it finds nothing..  even I tried to paste the line many times in a new test file and search or replace it, but if found nothing..  that line I mean: <script src="/resources/common.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: @Mike: I can't reproduce this. I have added a screenshot that shows how EPP should be setup (it's the German version, but should be able to get the idea).

Comment: @Mike: This appears to be an older version of EditPad. Does checking the `Dot Matches Newline` option change anything?

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using positive lookbehind which is used for finding and **not** matching, you can use this to find the first occurrence of your line, then matching the rest of occurrences.

Try This one. It will match all the occurrences of your line except the first one.

`(?<=<script src=./resources/common.js..+?</script>.*?)(<script src=./resources/common.js..+?</script>)`

***note***: Positive lookbehinds may or may not work depending on the regex engine you are using, but it should work in most cases.*

---

**More info:**
[Regular Expression Lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: This would only find the first duplicate; also it will only work in .NET languages or EditPadPro, definitely not in Notepad++.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Actually, by trying this pattern on RegexBuddy using JGSoft, it matches all but the first occurrence. And I do not know if this would work on Notepad++. Even if it doesn't, he could use anything else. I think Notepad++ is not the constraint here.

Comment: Yes, but RegexBuddy does use the JGSoft regex engine (like EditPadPro), so you can't generalize the result for other editors. Click on the Use tab and choose Perl to see what I mean.

Comment: @TimPietzcker yes I understand what you mean, that's why I left the note above.